Charles Map Local: Is it possible to partially ignore filenames for an Angular App?
I'm trying to use map local for development on an angular application.
It works well for images or jsons, or anything else that doesn't have it's name uglified
However in angular, files are built with an extra name moved to the middle of it's filename.
e.g, the styles file is:
styles.random text and numbers.css
how can I map local in a way that ignores the text between two dots here? Is it possible?
map local to directory works for images and jsons, but not styles or js files as they are given a random middle name to their file

Can't find it in the docs, but there is this setting in angular.json outputHashing with which you can configure output hashing (the random text & numbers you see between file name and extension). Also there is a CLI flag ng build --output-hashing=none. However, it is not advisable to use this in production, as output hashing the most efficient and reliant caching mechanism.
